# SpriteKit physics simulation bounce error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, simulation, physics, breakout

I have a simple breakout game which consists of a node being the ball and some other objects. The problem is when the ball bounces against the wall at a very small angle, it doesn't bounce back, it just slides against the wall indefinitely.

Manually calculating the angle after the contact could solve the problem, though it would be nice to use the physics provided by `SpriteKit`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // screen border setup
    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    border.allowsRotation = true
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 1
    border.linearDamping = 0
    border.angularDamping = 0

    physicsBody = border
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    // bottom edge setup
    let rect = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.size.width, height: 2)
    let bottom = SKNode()
    bottom.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: rect)
    bottom.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BottomCategory
    addChild(bottom)

    // ball setup
    let ball = childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 30, dy: -30))
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BlockCategory | BottomCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BallCategory

    // paddle setup
    let paddle = childNode(withName: "paddle") as! SKSpriteNode
    paddle.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PaddleCategory
}
```

Comment: This is a known issue with the physics engine, try searching on here for a similar issue, I know it has been talked about before